# Kähler differential relative to $\mathbb Q$

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra

If $K:k$ is a finite extension, then a classical result says the Kähler differential $\Omega^1_{K/k}=0$ if and only if $K:k$ is separable. Now any algebraic extension of the rational field $\mathbb Q$ is necessarily separable hence $\Omega^1_{K/\mathbb Q}=0$ if and only if $K$ is a number field.

**My question:** What do we know about $\Omega^1_{K/\mathbb Q}$ when $K$ is not a number field or just arbitrary field of characteristic zero?

My question is motivated from studying the following exact sequence of sheaves of differentials

$\pi^*\Omega^1_{K/\mathbb Q}\rightarrow \Omega^1_{X/\mathbb Q}\rightarrow\Omega^1_{X/K}\rightarrow 0$

where $X$ is a (projective) variety over a field $K$ of characteristic zero and $\pi$ is the structural morphism.

Comment: It is $K$ vectorspace of dimension equal to the transcendence degree of $K$ over the rationals.